# Does using removeIf() on an ArrayBlockingQueue trigger a put() call from another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue, remove-if

I'm trying to remove elements manually from `ArrayBlockingQueue` by using the `removeIf()` method, using threads.
And then have another thread trying to put an element into the `ArrayBlockingQueue`.
It doesn't work, which is weird because I thought that `put()` tries and tries until there's space and puts an element in successfully or is my understanding of it wrong?

What's the problem and what should I do to work around this problem?

Here's my code

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;


class HelloWorld {
    
    static ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue(2);
    static CyclicBarrier cb = new CyclicBarrier(2);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    q.put(2);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    q.put(2);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            Thread t3 = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    q.put(1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            t3.start();
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            System.out.println(q.size());
            q.removeIf(ii -> ii == 2);
            System.out.println(q.size());
            t3.join();
            System.out.println(q.size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The first output was 2, second was 0 after the removeIf() method and the third output never arrived, I think its because the put() method was never triggered.
I expected the third output to be 1 as I thought the put() method will be triggered as space was vacated using removeIf(), but the third output never came no matter how long I waited

Comment: Never write empty catch blocks. Always log or rethrow the exception, if you must catch it.

Comment: Threads execute asynchronously.  That means the two threads you created may not have completed yet, or even started executing.  If you need to test this, you should use some signal (like a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) or `.join()`) so you can execute after they're done.

Comment: Please show a complete, runnable example.

Comment: @markspace ah sorry it wasn't shown in the code above but I used CyclicBarrier to wait for the thread to finish before printing q.size()

Comment: @tgdavies I see, alright I have now added in suitable code to not make it empty

Comment: @tgdavies I have now included the code for the whole file

Comment: As your `CyclicBarrier` is waiting for one thread, await will return as soon as your main thread calls `await`, i.e. before your other threads have completed. You need to wait for 4 threads and call `await` from your other threads.

Comment: @tgdavies hey sorry I can't quite follow, do you mean I should set the parameter for CyclicBarrier to 4?

Comment: Your `CyclicBarrier` doesn't know about the other threads -- and they don't know about it. Read the Javadoc for `CyclicBarrier`.

Comment: @tgdavies understood, I've now made changes so as to not use CyclicBarrier but used Thread.join() instead, however the third output never arrives, even after t3.join() does that mean removeIf() does not trigger the put() method?

Comment: Have a look at the source code of `ArrayBlockingQueue`. Look at the `Condition` `put` waits on, look at where it gets signalled. Will it get signalled by `removeIf`?

Comment: ohh, it doesn't get signalled by removeIf,
but in that case, is there a work around to this?

Comment: Iterate queue and use ```remove``` method?